# Need to change an ImageView in custom ArrayAdapter class

Tags: android, listview, sdk

I am using the custome view class below and I want to change the ImageView icon when someone selects a view in my list in onListItemClick. How do I get the view? In my OnCreate, I have

```
    iconicAdapter = new IconicAdapter();
    setListAdapter(iconicAdapter);
```

Then in my custom view class, I have

```
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
IconicAdapter() {
    super(myApp.this, R.layout.row, title_list);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    TextView title=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
    title.setText(title_list.get(position).toString());
    ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    return(row);
}
```

}

What do I need in the method below to access the correct ImageView icon in my custom view class? Or should I access it a different way?

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do the following:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageBitmap(anyBitmap); 
    //((YourCustomAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    //or
    //v.invalidate();
}
```

later you can set any resource to your image view, bitmap, drawable, etc.

cheers